# How can web developer see user console errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was wondering what is the best way (or different options) for a web developer to be alerted to console errors that are logged by other users (who are logged in). I'm using Express / Passport connected to MongoDB. The errors could be on the client or server side. I was guessing I could somehow send the error to the database and access it through there. Alternately I could use something like mailgun to email them to myself, but I was wondering if there were better ways of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: you can use some application monitoring tools like sentry https://github.com/getsentry/sentry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are different ways to do this. But the important point is that you must classify the system errors and consider an information system for each. For example, for critical errors that cause the system to crash, you need to have a module for sending SMS directly, or use modules to send messages to one of your social networks.

Good for second-rate errors with less priority for email and error storage.

For low-priority errors and warnings, you need to have a log storage system that stores logged records and [monitors relevant processing](https://stackify.com/best-log-management-tools/) and error processing from your stored information. Graylog is OK! :)

The `Winston` module is usually used to display errors in Express.
 And in the first layer, if you use PM2, it automatically saves the logs in a text file.